# Node/ES6 import. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import при запуске приложения

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

Решил использовать [react-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbar) для кастомизации скроллбаров на сайте. В [мануале](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbar#usage-examples) по использованию, указывается нодовский импорт модуля

```js
var ScrollArea = require('react-scrollbar');

    var App = React.createClass({
      render() {
        return (
          <ScrollArea
            speed={0.8}
            className="area"
            contentClassName="content"
            horizontal={false}
            >
            <div>Some long content.</div>
          </ScrollArea>
        );
      }
    });
```

сборка происходит успешно, однако при запуске приложения я получаю ошибку

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string 
(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but 
got: object
```

Использую ES6 импорт

```
import ScrollArea from 'react-scrollbar/src/js/ScrollAreaWithoutCss'
```

и получаю другую ошибку

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

по какой-то причине ругается на первую строчку файла модуля

```
import ScrollArea from './ScrollArea.jsx';

export default ScrollArea;
```

где допускаю ошибку?

---

Конфиг с babel

```js
module: {
      preloaders:[{
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          loaders: ['eslint']
      }],
      loaders: [{
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          loaders: ['babel'],
          exclude: [
            /(node_modules|bower_components)/
          ]
        }]
      ...
```

.babelrc

```js
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": ['transform-runtime', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
}
```

Comment: по второму пункту вебпак-1 не понимает из коробки es6 импорты, Обычно они обрабатываются бабелем, то есть в loaders должен быть babel-loader

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму бабель с нужными пресетами уже установлен - "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]. сборка происходит успешно, ошибку получаю при попытку обновить страницу приложения. до этого местами использовал возможности es7 и не возникало проблем. может я что-то еще упустил?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму чем отличаются пресеты - stage-0, 1, 2?

Comment: видимо упустили. Конфг вебпака покажите. Про пресеты: каждая js-фича проходит несколько этапов до попадания в стандарт в ходе которых она меняется. stage-3 - только фичи самые близкие к попаданию в актуальный стандарт, stage-0 - самые нестабильные плюс фичи из более высоких пресетов.. Подробнее в доках бабеля. https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму обновил вопрос конфигом. бандл же собирается, значит вебпак обрабатывает корректно. ошибка проявляется в консоли браузера

Comment: навскидку выглядит норм, возможно он babelrc не подтягивает. "до этого местами использовал возможности es7 и не возникало проблем". Может Вы использовали возможности поддерживаемые нативно в том браузере который смотрели?) Код реально транспилировался? Возьмите запилите тупо файл с одной стрелочной функцией и посмотрите преобразится ли он в результате сборки в function()

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму да, реально. уже куча стрелочных функций, биндинг через :: , все преобразуется

Comment: а конкретно тот файл в котором ругается на импорт он точно транспилит? Попробуйте конструкцию там и посмотрите во что она превратится

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму этот файл принадежит скаченному модулю, а у меня папки с модулями лежат в эксклюде. я правильно понимаю, что модуль сам по себе уже должен быть работоспособен и я в него не лезу, только импортирую по надобности?

Comment: да. Но ругается то у вас на строчку в файле с импортом который ваш. Вот его точно бабель обрабатывает?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму так я немного запутался, как должен выглядеть транслированный импорт import ScrollArea from './ScrollArea.jsx' ? как модуль RequiereJS? да, и кстати в модуле лежит свой конфиг вебпака, который в качестве пресета содержит stage-2. Как это может влиять?

Answer (score 1):

По первому пункту: попробуйте установить последнюю версию react-router.
По второму пункту: Утка правильно советует, это будет примерно так:

Установка:

```
npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 webpack --save-dev
```

Использование в webpack:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: не пойму причем здесь реакт-роутер? по второму пункту - бабель с нужными пресетами уже установлен - "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]. сборка происходит успешно, ошибку получаю при попытку обновить страницу приложения с новой сборкой. до этого местами использовал возможности es7 и не возникало проблем. может я что-то еще упустил?